# Allow tableview cell to be selected based on url string

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am creating a "favorite pages" menu in my tableview application, where users can save their favorite web pages and then navigate to them easier through the menu.

The program saves the name of the page and the URL for each favorite page slot in the settings app. The default URL is "clear" meaning there is no URL yet (i.e. the favorite slot is not in use).

When a user clicks on a tableview cell for their desired favorite page, the view switches to a `UIWebview` and the URL is loaded. I made it so that if the URL `isEqualToString @"clear"`, the `UIWebView` will not load display and "nothing" will happen.

But when the user clicks on the tableview cell with a URL set to "clear", the cell is still highlighted in blue. This makes it appear to the user that the tableview cell is not cleared. Is there anyway to check if the URL `isEqualToString @"clear"` and stop the cell from highlighting blue before it does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This is a better way (doing it in willSelect... is too late on the first tap).

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       ...
       if ( --THIS IS THE 'CLEAR' URL CASE-- ) {
            // This will prevent the **appearance** of being selected
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
       } else {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
       }
       ...
  }
```

In  didSelectCellForIndexPath...

```
 if ( -- 'CLEAR' CASE -- ) {
       // Do nothing...
 } else {
       // do whatever you do for the selected case...
 }
```

Comment: But how would instruct the cell to not be selected and instead do nothing?

Comment: Should I reset the selection style after or does it reset automatically? When the user clicks on an actual URL I want it to still highlight.

Comment: It will not reset automatically.  You should set it explicitly for each cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: But the selection style change only effects that cell if it has the URL value of "clear", correct? If so, it should be fine.

Comment: True, but tableview cells are reused, and you have no control over which old one you'll get when a particular cell scrolls into view.

Comment: So you're saying that I should set it for each cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath before the user clicks at all?

Comment: Yes, and that's a good habit to get into.  (Trust me on this one...).  I updated the code, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *url = [self urlForIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([url isEqualToString:@"clear"])
        return nil;

    return indexPath;
}
```

But if you don't want the blue highlight, you should also change the selectionStyle of the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`